# How to get the width property of a control in code behind ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

Is there a way to get the width property of controls in code behind? I need to add dynamic controls to panels and make the width 20px less then the panel. So I am trying to do this in Page_Load event but the width property is not an integer or string.

Comment: Do you mean the css style attribute ?

Comment: Not all controls have a Width property.  What dynamic controls are you trying to create?

Comment: I am not setting the css width, but the property width. Im dynamically creating Textbox, Panel, Dropdownlist, radiobutton, checkbox controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Double myPanelWidth = myControlPanel.Width.Value;
```

That will give you a the width as a double.

Then you could do this:

```
myControl.Width.Value = myPanelWidth - 20;
```

Comment: @Algorythm Thank you, I put a panel on a page, set the property to 250px and in code behind used your suggestion and it worked great. But I switched your code to myControl.Width.Value

Comment: @Icarus: Fixed it!  Yea, I messed up the order. Thanks!

Comment: @algorhythm And the capitalization of the properties is also wrong; your code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 3):

The Width poperty is of type Unit. You can set the value programmatically using something like:

```
yourControl.Width=new Unit("20 px");
```

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit.aspx

Comment: @lcarus Thanks, I see how that works but any way to get the width property as opposed to setting it?

Comment: That's what the Value and Type properties of the Width property are for. You should be able to get length and type by doing: control.Width.Value And control.Width.Type respectively. Check the documentation I linked.

Comment: @lcarus Thank you, I breezed through it to quick to catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to set the width through code as you explained but also accounting for unit type:

```
Dim dblTargetWidth As Double = pnlMyPanel.Width.Value - 20
ctrlMyControl.Width = New Unit(dblTargetWidth, pnlMyPanel.Width.Type)
```